# how to make widget update every few seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I got the widget from https://coinmarketcap.com/widget/?c=bitcoin and I'm not too sure how to make it update every few seconds or minutes because at the moment it doesn't update unless I refresh the page. If anyone could help that would be great.

here is the code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/widget/currency.js"></script><div class="coinmarketcap-currency-widget" data-currency="bitcoin" data-base="USD" data-secondary="" data-ticker="true" data-rank="true" data-marketcap="true" data-volume="true" data-stats="USD" data-statsticker="false"></div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/widget/currency.js"></script>
<div id="mainContainer" class="coinmarketcap-currency-widget" data-currency="bitcoin" data-base="ZAR" data-secondary="" data-ticker="true" data-rank="true" data-marketcap="true" data-volume="true" data-stats="ZAR" data-statsticker="true"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, in your case you could refresh your page every few seconds with either a meta refresh or javascript. But that would make the whole page flicker. Unless you put that code inside an `iframe`

Comment: Yes I could but I would prefer just the div to be refreshed (i know the javascript for this) but when I do this the content doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your script won't render an `iframe` and only renders it once it is loaded, you need to reattach the script every few seconds:

```js
const redrawElements = {
  div: {
    id: 'mainContainer',
    'class': 'coinmarketcap-currency-widget',
    'data-currency': 'bitcoin',
    'data-base': 'ZAR',
    'data-secondary': '',
    'data-ticker': 'true',
    'data-rank': 'true',
    'data-marketcap': 'true',
    'data-volume': 'true',
    'data-stats': 'ZAR',
    'data-statsticker': 'true',
  },
  script: {
    src: 'https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/widget/currency.js',
  },
}
const redrawContainer = document.querySelector( '.draw-container' );

function redraw() {
  redrawContainer.innerHTML = '';
  
  // Recreate elements
  Object.keys( redrawElements ).forEach( el => {
    const domEl = document.createElement( el );
    // Iterate over attributes
    Object.keys( redrawElements[ el ] ).forEach( attr => {
      domEl.setAttribute( attr, redrawElements[ el ][ attr ] );
    } );
    redrawContainer.appendChild( domEl );
  } );
}
redraw();
// Redraw every 10 seconds
setInterval( redraw, 10000 );
```

```css
.draw-container {
  min-height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<p>This is your content, which should stay the same</p>
<div class="draw-container"></div>
<p>And because <code>.draw-container</code> has a min-height, your content should not jump around.</p>
```

Comment: This works! Thanks so much! I really appreciate it. You saved me big time!

Comment: You are welcome. But keep in mind, this is a bit hacky :) better to build your own widget if you have the time and energy.

Comment: Yes. this is just for now purposes. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Use SetInterval function to add the source of iframe. so that only the div will be refreshed.

```
setInterval(()=>{$('iframe').prop('src','widget-url')},1000)
```

Comment: And the `iframe` is where?

Comment: forget iframe clear the html or div every second and add the html again to a div. Like
var widgetHtml = "<script type="text/javascript" src="https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/widget/currency.js"></script>
<div id="mainContainer" class="coinmarketcap-currency-widget" data-currency="bitcoin" data-base="ZAR" data-secondary="" data-ticker="true" data-rank="true" data-marketcap="true" data-volume="true" data-stats="ZAR" data-statsticker="true"></div>"
<div id="widget"></div>

setInterval(()=>{$('#widget').html("");
$('#widget').html("widgetHtml")
},1000)

Comment: Why it wouldn't work, we are clearing the html and append again, so it will possible make a call again and get the latest data.

Comment: Then please update your answer showing a working example :)